# Bollinger Bands Using Talib

Tags: java, eclipse, finance

I am trying to implement a simple BBands application using talib.

I do not have any expirience in Talib and technical Indicators.

Can someone have a look at say whether this is a good implementation of Bollinger Bands using Talib and give me advice how can it be improved. If anyone has expirience with Talib and Bollinger Bands it would be much appriciated to give me a hand. Here is the code.

```
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.Core;
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.MInteger;
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.RetCode;
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.*;
import com.tictactec.ta.lib.meta.helpers.*;

public class ExampleTALib 
{

  /**
   * The total number of periods to generate data for.
   */
  public static final int TOTAL_PERIODS = 100;

  /**
    * The number of periods to average together.
    */
  public static final int PERIODS_AVERAGE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      double[] closePrice = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];
      double[] out = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];
      MInteger begin = new MInteger();
      MInteger length = new MInteger();

      double[] outRealUpperBand = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];
      double[] outRealMiddleBand = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];
      double[] outRealLowerBand = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];




      for (int i = 0; i < closePrice.length; i++) {
        closePrice[i] = (double) i;
      }

      Core c = new Core();
//      RetCode retCode = c.sma(0, closePrice.length - 1, closePrice, PERIODS_AVERAGE, begin, length, out);
//      RetCode re = c.sma(startIdx, endIdx, inReal, optInTimePeriod, outBegIdx, outNBElement, outReal)
      RetCode retCode = c.bbands(0, closePrice.length - 1, closePrice, PERIODS_AVERAGE,
              1.0, 3.0, MAType.Ema, begin, length, outRealUpperBand, outRealMiddleBand, outRealLowerBand);
//      RetCode re = c.bbands(startIdx, endIdx, inReal, optInTimePeriod, optInNbDevUp, optInNbDevDn, optInMAType, outBegIdx, outNBElement, outRealUpperBand, outRealMiddleBand, outRealLowerBand)


      if (retCode == RetCode.Success) {
        System.out.println("Output Begin:" + begin.value);
        System.out.println("Output Begin:" + length.value);

        for (int i = begin.value; i < closePrice.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
            line.append("Period #");
            line.append(i+1);
            line.append(" close= ");
            line.append(closePrice[i]);
            line.append(" mov avg=");
            line.append(out[i-begin.value]);
            System.out.println(line.toString());
            }
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Error");
    }
  }
}
```